# Building a classifier with only examples for one class

Tags: machine-learning, classification

My company makes widgets. We make very high quality widgets, but occasionally a widget will suffer a defect known as a 'glurb'. A widget might never glurb over its entire lifetime, it may glurb once, or it may glurb multiple times. A widget's lifetime may be a few months or many years.

We maintain a database that lists every instance of a widget glurbing. For each glurb event, we know which widget glurbed, when it glurbed, and we have features about the widget before it glurbed. We know for 100% certain that when a widget glurbs, it is recorded in our database.

Management wants to build a machine learning model that, given a particular widget, will predict whether or not it will glurb in, say, the next six months.

I have a problem: I have a set of observations that show when a widget glurbs, which is the 'positive' training set, but I have no 'negative' (did not glurb) training set.

Is it statistically valid for me to choose a time, date, and widget at random, look into my database, and if I see that widget didn't glurb for 6 months after the chosen date/time, to declare that as an instance of a 'didn't glurb' event and put that in my 'negative' training set sample?

Is there a statistically valid way to generate a 'negative' test set from the data I have? If so, what would it be? If not, how could I build a classifier from the data I have?

Comment: Ignoring the specific task and only giving a keyword: lookup [PU-learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-class_classification).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is valid to do so. Depending what your management division asked, you are 100% correct. You will be predicting by definition **if a widget will glurb within the next 6 months or not**.

Just remember the problem that this is a different problem than predicting *when* a widget will glurb or *if* it will in its lifetime.

Answer (score 0):

There has been some research on "one-class classification".  Here are a couple of papers:

- [One-class classification](http://homepage.tudelft.nl/n9d04/thesis.pdf) by David Martinus Johannes
- [Learning Deep Features for One-Class Classification](https://arxiv.org/abs/1801.05365) by Pramuditha Perera, Vishal M. Patel
  The code implementation is available here: https://github.com/PramuPerera/DeepOneClass

If your data is in the form of images, you could try using Generative Adversarial Networks (GANs) to generate negative data.  There is a post on this problem here: [Could I use GANs to generate negative samples for one class classification?](https://www.quora.com/Could-I-use-GANs-to-generate-negative-samples-for-one-class-classification)  He references Johannes' thesis.

If you program in Python check out what SciKit-Learn has to offer:

- [sklearn.svm.OneClassSVM](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.OneClassSVM.html#sklearn.svm.OneClassSVM)
- Example: [One-class SVM with non-linear kernel (RBF)](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/svm/plot_oneclass.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-svm-plot-oneclass-py)